# Difference between System.exit(0); and Platform.exit();?

Tags: java, javafx, system.exit

Someone here suggested using the latter. I'm a newbie in java, just wondering.. what's the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can very well google it, why do you want to post it here anyways?

Comment: System.exit(system call) terminates the currently running Java virtual machine by initiating its shutdown sequence. The argument serves as a status code. By convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination. On Unix and Linux systems, 0 for successful executions and 1 or higher for failed executions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `System.exit(...)` terminates the **JVM**, stopping everything immediately.

`Platform.exit()` just signals the **JavaFX Toolkit** to shut down, so the application instance `stop()`.